# ngingx allow single IP AND internal requests

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to setup an nginx server to allow requests from a single IP and as well internal requests. The reason being that this box could be hit directly, or via a proxy_pass. I haven't been able to find a way to mix allow AND internal. In an ideal world I'd like to do something like this:

```
   location = /myFile.html {
         # allow to permit proxy_pass from other box
         allow XX.X.X.XX;
         # allow internal requests
         internal;
         # deny everything else
         deny all;
   }
```

I've read through the documentation, and haven't been able to find the right combination of directives to allow for this.

Answer (score 1):

`internal` location will accept requests from `rewrite`, `try_files`, etc. **and** SSI requests (they are considered *internal* in the scope of primary outer request)

Answer (score 0):

The internal directive is to restrict access only to internal request and it is not possible to use it in conjunction with allow. Instead of using internal, why don't you use **allow 127.0.0.1** ?

```
internal indicates that the matching location can be used only for so called "internal" requests.
```

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#internal